# match_parent layout parameter doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to create a view for an ArrayAdapter. This is how I'm doing it:

```
FrameLayout rowView = new FrameLayout(context);
rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp2.setMargins(0, 0,
    context.getResources()
        .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_divider_small), 0);
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.textView1);

ImageView view = new ImageView(context);
int size = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
        R.dimen.image_avatar_size);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp0 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.va);
rowView.addView(view, lp0);

Button btn = new Button(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
        R.dimen.activity_margin);
btn.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
btn.setText(okButtonText);
btn.setId(R.id.textView1);

RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
layout.addView(rowView, lp2);
layout.addView(btn, lp);
```

My intent is to stretch the textView with OK caption vertically. For some reason button does not match its parent proeperly. Could anyone point me at my mistake?

**EDIT** Things are getting really weird. It is known that if we set both ALIGN_PARENT_TOP and ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM parameters, the view will be stretched vertically. In my case, the view is placed on bottom of layout (like if i set the ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM only).

*This is what I get:*

http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/3323/jqs.png

**EDIT**

Well, this issue looks kinda like the platform bug, so I had to add a listener that resizes OK button.

```
rowView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int height = rowView.getHeight();
        btn.setHeight(height);
    }
});
```

I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Why you didn't create an xml file ?

Comment: Actually I did, but there was the same issue, so I tried to do this manually.

Comment: Have you tried to `setBackground()` instead of? And in XML file should your to but with `android:background` instead of `android:src`.

Comment: @yugidroid I've just tried this - unsuccessfully.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try adding the `Button` before adding the `FrameLayout`?

Comment: @Luksprog Adding `Button` before `FameLayout` was one of my very first suggestions, but it didn't work.

Comment: The alignment relative to the parent bounds should work. Maybe you could try aligning the `Button` relative to the `FrameLayout` with the `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP` and `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM` rules.

Answer (score 0):

you should try layout.addView(btn,lp);

Comment: Nope, nothing's changed.

Comment: And if you change TextView to Button ?

Comment: The button doesn't scale too.

Comment: That's strange. Perhaps because you are in a listView. You could try align the button to the other view with RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM porperty

Comment: could you post shape_background ?

Comment: I've added this XML to m post.

Comment: Try with a background color like btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); in order to be sure of the size of your view. Are you still using a Button view ?

Comment: I've edited my post. And yes, I am using Button at the moment.

Comment: Ok, i tried by myself and has the same thing as you. The only woraround i found is to set tes size of your button : RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          size);

Comment: Since rows in my real project could contain an arbitrary amount of text, setting the constant size is not a good idea. So I've added the listener as described in my post.